# Live streaming HLS via ffmpeg, How to force client to start playing from the beginning? From 1st segment

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

Is there a way, maybe via an ffmpeg option or flag, to force the client player to always start the playlist from the beginning when live streaming rather than the real time mid-stream?

Say the user comes in 1mn after the stream has started, rather than starting to watch at 1mn the player would start at the beginning of the video so minute zero.

Here is my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f "screen capture" -s 1280x720 -r 30 -i :0.0+nomouse -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -async 30 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -b:a 64k -threads 0 -s 640x360 -f hls -g 1 -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 1 -hls_allow_cache 0 /hls/#{@stream_name}/index.m3u8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-hls_list_size 0` to keep all segments in the playlist. Using a value greater than 0 will cause the playlist to use a sliding window of `hls_list_size` length.

Also of note, using `-hls_time 1` will greatly increase your playlist file size. The Apple recommended value is 6 seconds so you should try to increase it to a multiple of your desired keyframe interval.

Comment: Thanks will try that, I'm trying to keep the hls_time value low as this is a live stream and I would like to keep the time it takes my player to find the playlist and start playing low, it seems the player is waiting for a few segments before starting to play, so the longer the hls_time the higher the delay it seems. You know of another solution to this delay problem?

Comment: It needs 3 segments before playback. Using hls-time is not enough though, you also need to specify a keyframe interval of 1s. You can use the **-g**  (GOP size) option for that. Eg: -g 30 will insert an iframe each 30 frames and since your framerate is 30 fps that translates to 1 iframe / s

Comment: Apple recommneded `-hls_time` is 6

Comment: @Abhay Yes, they changed the value in the meantime.